# Convert indian time zone to local time

Tags: android, timezone, simpledateformat, datetime-format, gmt

In my app I am getting time from server in API in IST timezone, I want to show time in device's local time zone.

Below is my code for this but it seems its not working.

```
SimpleDateFormat serverSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
SimpleDateFormat utcSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
SimpleDateFormat localSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
serverSDF.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Calcutta"));
utcSDF.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
localSDF.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());

Date serverDate = serverSDF.parse(dateString);
String utcDate = utcSDF.format(serverDate);
Date localDate = localSDF.parse(utcDate);
```

From server I am getting time `"2018-02-28 16:04:12"` in IST and the code above displays `"Wed Feb 28 10:34:12 GMT+05:30 2018"`.

Comment: If possible, modify your server to send GMT format. And in client side convert accordingly. Else, get in IST format, convert to GMT and then convert to local timezone.

https://www.journaldev.com/696/how-to-convert-java-date-into-specific-timezone-format

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Timezone conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567923/timezone-conversion)

Comment: Please search before posting your question and find a good answer faster. This question has been asked and answered with minor variations over and over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:** Check [this answer by @istt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49029315/9019332) which uses modern Java8 date-time api.

You don't need to change format in UTC first. You can simply use:

```
SimpleDateFormat serverSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
SimpleDateFormat localSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
serverSDF.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata"));
localSDF.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());

String localDate = localSDF.format(serverSDF.parse(dateString));
```

Comment: The terrible classes used here are long obsolete, supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. See the correct solution in the [Answer by istt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49029315/642706).

Comment: @BasilBourque you are correct, use Java8 classes, they are modern and immutable, use them.

Answer (score 3):

The other answer uses **GMT+05:30**, but it's much better to use a proper timezone such as **Asia/Kolkata**. It works now because India currently uses the +05:30 offset, but it's not guaranteed to be the same forever.

If someday the government decides to change the country's offset (which [already happened in the past](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/india/kolkata?year=1925)), your code with a hardcoded **GMT+05:30** will stop working - but a code with **Asia/Kolkata** (and a [JVM with the timezone data updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48630833/how-is-java-util-timezone-daylight-info-updated)) will keep working.

But today there's a better API to manipulate dates, see here how to configure it: [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project)

This is better than `SimpleDateFormat`, a class known to have tons of problems: https://eyalsch.wordpress.com/2009/05/29/sdf/

With this API, the code would be:

```
String serverDate = "2018-02-28 16:04:12";
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
LocalDateTime istLocalDate = LocalDateTime.parse(serverDate, fmt);

// set the date to India timezone
String output = istLocalDate.atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"))
    // convert to device's zone
    .withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.systemDefault())
    // format
    .format(fmt);
```

In my machine, the output is `2018-02-28 07:34:12` (it varies according to the default timezone of your environment).

Although it seems complicated to learn a new API, in this case I think it's totally worth it. The new API is much better, easier to use (once you learn the concepts), less error-prone, and fix lots of problems of the old API.

Check Oracle's tutorial to learn more about it: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/